# NuxtJS with Babel 7: still have spread operator in built files

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vue.js, babeljs, nuxt.js

I'm desperately trying to make my NuxtJS app work with IE11. I implemented babel config in many ways to build a compatible version but I still have spread operators in built pages files, as if Babel didn't transform Nuxt code.

Here is my config:

*nuxt.config.js*

```
const pkg = require('./package')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  // ...

  build: {
    babel: {
      babelrc: true
    },
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'));

      const svgRule = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.test.test('.svg'));

      svgRule.test = /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$/;

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'vue-svg-loader',
      }, {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
  "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": false }]],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]]
    }
  }
}
```

*.browserslistrc*

```
# Browsers that we support

>0.2%
not dead
not ie < 11
not op_mini all
```

Despite that config, I still see some spread operators used in Nuxt built pages, like the following generated by nuxt:

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["pages/events/_slug.pages/index"],{

/***/ "./assets/svg/events/market.svg":
/*!**************************************!*\
  !*** ./assets/svg/events/market.svg ***!
  \**************************************/
/*! exports provided: default */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);

      /* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = ({
        functional: true,
        render(_h, _vm) {
          const { _c, _v, data, children = [] } = _vm;

          const {
            class: classNames,
            staticClass,
            style,
            staticStyle,
            attrs = {},
            ...rest
          } = data;
```

I searched from some time across different issues about NuxtJS and Babel, but Nuxt claims that it works with IE9 without extra Babel configuration, which is not the case here. I'd like to understand why the code is not transpiled the right way.

Comment: nuxt transpile to ie9 by default. You dont need to change preset. The only way you could get that code is if its from 3rd party lib from your node modules. Then u need to add it to transpile property in your nuxt config

Comment: You're right, with this clue I found out that the culprit for this in my case is vue-svg-loader, which convert my SVG assets to ES6 components with spread operators. Great thanks for your help :) !

Comment: https://github.com/Developmint/nuxt-svg-loader/

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue: A Nuxt app wouldn't work in the Edge browser because of spread operators in *@nuxtjs/axios* and *bootstrap-vue*. I did find a solution.

The *build* property in *nuxt.config.js* should be defined as follows:

```
build: {
    babel: {
      babelrc: true,
      configFile: './babel.config.js'
    },
    transpile: [ '@nuxtjs/axios', 'bootstrap-vue' ],
    // Other config
}
```

The *transpile* property is key here. Internally, Nuxt defines an *exclude* for *babel-loader* that ignores everything in *node_modules*, unless it's in *transpile*.

Using *babel.config.js* also appears to matter, and the official Babel documentation says you should use it if you want to process *node_modules*.

*babel.config.js*:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        sourceType: 'unambiguous',
        presets: ['@nuxt/babel-preset-app'],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
    };
}
```

You don't need *include* or *exclude* here, as it's taken care of by Nuxt, as noted.